# get the url in the middleware laravel

Tags: url, laravel, middleware

I have my middleware and inside it I am trying to reach the current url of the page. so I did something like that:

`$url = Request::url();`

and I used:

`use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

but I keep getting the following error:

`Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::url() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

any ideas?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can access the url from the Request Object:

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
 {
      $url = $request->url();
      ...
 }
```

`Request` object has also `fullUrl()` and `path()` methods. Choose the one that fit your needs

Comment: is there any method that returns the url pattern like  entities/{id}/queries?

Comment: I need to get the url with name of param in url, no with value. do u know howw??
-> foo/{bar} instead of ->foo/valueBar

Comment: FOUND IT! @GaurabDahal $request->route()->uri()

Answer (score 8):

In Laravel 5 the request is already passed into the `handle()` function

```
class MyMiddleware {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $url = $request->url();

        // Do stuff here

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Laravel 5 tries to move away from facades (e.g: Calls such as `Request::url()`) in favour of using dependency injection, so you may notice some functions and such cannot be accessed the same as you did in 4.

Heres quite a nice explanation of dependency injection in Laravel 5 https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-method-injection

Comment: url is a method of the Request Object! So `$request->url()` is the right syntax.